# С#. Изменение текста веток в treeview

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, treeview

Столкнулся с проблемой. Я хочу чтобы в моей программе при изменения текста в treeview выполнялась команда UPDATE в базу данных. Я обрабатываю это в AfterEding, но не могу понять как мне получить новое значение после изменения текста в ветке.

```
 private void treeView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] IpHERE;
        string[] IpHERE2;
        TreeNode currentNode = treeView1.SelectedNode;
        IpHERE = currentNode.Text.Split(' ');
        string tmpCom = IpHERE[2];
        string tmpIP = IpHERE[1];

        if (IpHERE[0].Equals("Com"))
        {
            string query = string.Format("UPDATE comList SET port = @po, deviceNumber = @de, speed = @sp, bit = @bi, parity = @pa, stopBit = @st,  readTime = @re, writeTime = @wr Where port = @depo", myConnection);

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);

            IpHERE2 = currentNode.Text.Split(' ');

            command.Parameters.Add("@po",   IpHERE2[2]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@de",   IpHERE2[5]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@sp",   IpHERE2[7]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@bi",   IpHERE2[9]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@pa",   IpHERE2[11]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@st",   IpHERE2[13]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@re",   IpHERE2[15]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@wr",   IpHERE2[17]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@depo", tmpCom);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            statusLabel.Text = string.Format("Вы изменили: {0}", currentNode.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            string query = string.Format("UPDATE ipList SET ipAdres = @ip, port = @po, deviceNumber = @de, sendTime = @se, receiveTime = @re Where ipAdres = @ipO", myConnection);

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);

            IpHERE2 = currentNode.Text.Split(' ');

            command.Parameters.Add("@ip", IpHERE2[1]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@po", IpHERE2[4]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@de", IpHERE2[7]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@se", IpHERE2[9]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@re", IpHERE2[11]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@ipO", tmpIP);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            statusLabel.Text = string.Format("Вы изменили: {0}", currentNode.Text);
        }
    }
```

Я думал, что в массиве строк IpHERE будет лежать старая строка, а в IpHERE2 положу новые значения, но они там тоже старые.

А, еще может кто знает, в первом UPDATE, который для базы comList при попытки запуска: выдается ошибка - System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции UPDATE." А во втором ее нет. Хотя они вроде как одинаковые.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где нужно отловить новые значения. Спасибо.

Comment: [NodeLabelEditEventArgs.Label - Gets the new text to associate with the tree node](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.nodelabelediteventargs.label?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_NodeLabelEditEventArgs_Label)?

Comment: `Хотя они вроде как одинаковые` они не одинаковые

Comment: @tym32167 а чем они отличаются?

Comment: У вас апдейт на разные таблицы с разным набором параметров и, как следствие, это разные запросы никак не связанные друг с другом.

Comment: @tym32167 А я и не заметил... Реализация же одинаковая...  Спасибо за инфу с сайта microsoft, она мне помогла.

Comment: В обоих строках `string query = ...` уберите `string.Format` - вызов этого метода не нужен. Также не нужно там `myConnection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void treeView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => afterAfterEdit(e.Node)));            
    }

    private void afterAfterEdit(TreeNode node)
    {
        string txt = node.Text;

        string[] IpHERE2;
        TreeNode currentNode = treeView1.SelectedNode;
        IpHERE2 = txt.Split(' ');
        string tmpCom = IpHERE2[2];
        string tmpIP = IpHERE2[1];
        if (IpHERE2[0].Equals("Com"))
        {
            string query = string.Format("UPDATE comList SET port = @po, deviceNumber = @de, speed = @sp, bit = @bi, parity = @pa, stopBit = @st,  readTime = @re, writeTime = @wr Where port = @depo", myConnection);

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);

            command.Parameters.Add("@po", IpHERE2[2]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@de", IpHERE2[5]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@sp", IpHERE2[7]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@bi", IpHERE2[9]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@pa", IpHERE2[11]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@st", IpHERE2[13]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@re", IpHERE2[15]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@wr", IpHERE2[17]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@depo", tmpCom);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            statusLabel.Text = string.Format("Вы изменили: {0}", currentNode.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            string query = string.Format("UPDATE ipList SET ipAdres = @ip, port = @po, deviceNumber = @de, sendTime = @se, receiveTime = @re Where ipAdres = @ipO", myConnection);

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);

            command.Parameters.Add("@ip", IpHERE2[1]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@po", IpHERE2[4]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@de", IpHERE2[7]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@se", IpHERE2[9]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@re", IpHERE2[11]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@ipO", tmpIP);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            statusLabel.Text = string.Format("Вы изменили: {0}", currentNode.Text);
        }
    }
```